# Pipe docker logs -f into jq

Tags: docker

I'm trying to pipe json logs from docker into `jq`.
It works fine if I use:

```
docker logs container_id 2>&1 | jq '.'
```

But, if I try to tail it, it gets stuck.

```
docker logs -f container_id 2>&1 | jq '.'
```

While tailing by itself does work:

```
docker logs -f container_id 2>&1
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: AFAIK the command `docker logs container_id` shows plain text data so it is useless to redirect it to `jq`. The log files are indeed internally stored as json and json files. The path to log file for a particular container can be retrieved `docker inspect container_id | grep LogPath`. And the json can be continuously showed: `tail -f logfile | jq .`

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `--unbuffered --stream` so your command becomes

```
docker logs -f container_id 2>&1 | jq --unbuffered --stream '.'
```

It seems many other people have had a similar problem. Here are some bug reports on jq about this topic

- https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/477
- https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1530